# Refresh XML data from web in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba, web

I'm using Excel 2010 to link a table to a XML file on my server. I'd like to distribute the Excel file to a group of people and have it updated every time the XML file is updated on the server.

In Excel, I'm pulling the data using "Data", "From Web" and then I type in the path of the XML file.

Excel then builds a table with all the data but if the XML file is updated on the server, the data remains static, even if I click "Refresh" or "Refresh XML data" on the table.

It should be able to download new data including new columns to the table, if any.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in VBA , here what I will do
1. Refreshing when opening an Excel file , That can be done by

```
Sub RefreshData()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
' or you can give specific workbook and worksheet identification
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Call Refresh Data Subroutine when opening file
RefreshData

end sub
```

1. You can use worksheet activate event handler if you have multiple worksheet in a file.

   Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
     'Call Refresh Data Subroutine when opening file
       RefreshData
   End Sub
2. Updating MSexcel as soon as server gets update , doesn't make sense as data will be available for view only after file gets open , however if your macro is been used for live monitoring and kept open 24 hours then instead of sending a event from server and catching in VBA , I suggest implement polling every day/hour/minute/second ( call refresh at poll interval) depending upon your refresh requirement criticality.

   Dim TimeToRun

   Sub auto_open()
       Call Schedulerefresh
   End Sub

   Sub Schedulerefersh()
       TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

   ```
   Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "XMLRefersh"
   ```

   End Sub

   Sub XMLRefresh()

   'Call Refresh Data Subroutine when opening file
        RefreshData
       Call ScheduleRefresh
   End Sub

   Sub auto_close()
       On Error Resume Next
       Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "XMLRefresh", , False
   End Sub